# play and stop video tag that is created from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to play and stop video tag that is created from object tag but it returns the error that play is not function.

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>

<head/>
<body>
<object data="sample.mp4" name="VideoAdv" style="min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;position:absolute;bottom:0;" >
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
    <param name="loop" value="true" />
    <param name="controls" value="false" />
    <param name="autoplay" value="autoplay" />
<param name="Muted" value="true" />
</object>
<body/>
</html>
```

my jquery-js

```
$("[name=media]").play();
```

I use `name=media` because when I open html code in developer tools I see this

```html
<object data="sample.mp4" name="VideoAdv" style="min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;position:absolute;bottom:0;">
<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"></head><body>
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src=".../sample.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></body></html>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="loop" value="true">
    <param name="controls" value="false">
    <param name="autoplay" value="autoplay">
<param name="Muted" value="true">
</object>
```

So how can I play and stop video (no param that I wrote is working)?

Actually I want to show both video and image or sequence image just by changing name not change the js or html code. Is there any way except this one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Hopefully its working

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src=".../sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src=".../sample.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: i don't want to use <video> because i want show images too just by changing the name not change the video tag to image tag

Answer (score 0):

Well check this code. I'm only using youtube video for data.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <object data="https://www.youtube.com/v/tgbNymZ7vqY" name="VideoAdv" style="min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;position:absolute;bottom:0;" >
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <param name="loop" value="true" />
            <param name="controls" value="false" />
            <param name="autoplay" value="autoplay" />
            <param name="Muted" value="true" />
        </object>
    <body/>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tro4f8zh/

Comment: i have local media file for advertising